# How to write regex that match start with a letter, can contain letters, numbers, hyphens and 1 underscore?

Tags: regex

I need to write regex(.NET) that match string:
start with a letter, can contain letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, **1 underscore** and follow '@'. I tried the follow one, but it doesn't match 'a_bc12@' for example.

How to fix it?

`^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]+_{0,1}(?=@)`

EDITED:
 it should contain {3,10} length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to allow characters after the underscore again:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\.-]*_?[A-Za-z0-9\.-]*(?=@)/
```

Also, I've added the periods and made the strings before and after the underscore optional.

Comment: for curiosity, is there more short way?

Comment: I don't think so. Repetition will only be applicable with more than one allowed occurance of an underscore.

Comment: if I want to limit it to {3,10} length, how I can do it? this doesn't work `/^[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9\.-]*_?[A-Za-z0-9\.-]*){2,9}(?=@)/`

Comment: Then you should just match `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\._-]{2,9}(?=@)/` and check for the only one occurence of underscores afterwards. Regexes are unhelpful for counting :)

Comment: so I have to use 2 regex: 1 - ^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\._-]{2,9}(?=@) , 2 - ^[^_]*_?[^_](?=@) that will return `null` or match and thus I will know if there is only one underscore, right?

Comment: The second check will be much easier without regex but plain string methods. You could for example split by "_" and count the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify it as this:

```
[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-/.]*_[A-Za-z0-9-/.]*@`
```

when you use + after expression, it means "one or more times"
when you use * it means "zero or more times"

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-\.]*_{0,1}(?=@)
```

Your use of `+` is one or more occurences; you want zero or more following the intial letter, which is `*`.

Comment: There is not matching for periods in that pattern